# I cannot open localhost 8080

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I installed Vue-cli. There were no errors, localhost 8080 opened normally, but after that I closed the console and the localhost 8080 stopped working and did not open at all. How can I open localhost 8080? When I tried to enter npm run dev in the console such errors appear.

```
PS D:\tasksVue\blog\blog> npm run dev

> blog@1.0.0 dev D:\tasksVue\blog\blog
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI
-> When using npm: npm i -D webpack-cli
-> When using yarn: yarn add -D webpack-cli
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\tasksVue\blog\blog\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:77:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! blog@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the blog@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-25T18_04_46_023Z-debug.log
```

[Here is a screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbCn3.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI
-> When using npm: npm i -D webpack-cli
-> When using yarn: yarn add -D webpack-cli
```

Have you tried installing `webpack-cli` as stated?